# Socket.io - when I run my node app on localhost I can connect, but on the production server I can't?

Tags: node.js, sockets, iis, firewall

I'm using passport.socketio. The debug statements for the Authorization success are firing, but not the connect event. I get these debug statements on the server:

```
setting poll timeout
discarding transport
cleared post timeout for client laknraalkn3but
clearing poll timeout
jsonpolling writing to io.j[o]("8::");
set post timeout for client laknraalkn3but
jsonpolling closed due to exceeded duration
setting request GET /socket.io/1/jsonp-polling/laknraalkn3but
```

Not sure if this is the problem, but I'm trying to connect on port 8086, which some have told me could be too high of a port for a university web server. Where can I allow the ports? In the server firewall? I'm using windows server 2008 and IIS 7, and I've set up a reverse proxy to forward all traffic to port 8086.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a firewall issue, but without knowing your full setup, it's kind of impossible to diagnose.  Make sure port 8806 is open on the server, then see if there is a physical hardware firewall between you and the server and port 8806 is open on that as well.